# ¿Cómo puedo aplicar operadores lógicos en los tag de las plantillas de Django?

Tags: python, django, python-2.7, django-templates

Intento comparar una fecha ya registrada con la fecha actual del sistema por medio de un operador lógico (por ejemplo, `a < = b`) dentro de un tag de plantilla en Django 1.9.

```
{#acción que solo se habilitara para reactivar aĺ aliado si se cumplen dos condiciones#}

{% if  object.sancion_id == 1 and object.fecha_calcula_reactivacion < =  now "d-m-Y" %}
 <a class="btn btn-default" href="#reactivar_aliado" data-toggle="modal" title="Reactivación del aliado Comercial"> <i class="fa fa-cog" aria-hidden="true"></i></i></a>
{% endif %}
```

Comment: Puede mostrar su código actual?

Comment: Pruebe asi: `{% if  object.sancion_id == 1 and object.fecha_calcula_reactivacion|date:"d-m-Y" <=  now "d-m-Y" %}` a ver que sucede.

Comment: Error durante la representación de la plantilla

Comment: Se me complica no tengo como probarlo en este momento pruebe esto: `{% now "d-m-Y" as fecha %}
{% if object.sancion_id == 1 and   object.fecha_calcula_reactivacion <= fecha %}`

Comment: Lo que veo por lo que no puede estar funcionando es que al hacer la comparación, estás convirtiendo las fechas a `string` y no puedes comparar fechas por `string`. Así que te recomiendo quitar el filtro y el formato, y compara entre objetos sin más. Me cuentas que tal

Answer (score 1):

**Operadores Logicos en Template Django**

**igual(=)**

```
{% if variable == "x" %}
  esto aparecera si variable es igual a x
{% endif %}
```

**no igual(!=)**

```
{% if variable != "x" %}
  esto aparecera si la variable no es igual a x
{% endif %}
```

**Menor que (<)**

```
{% if variable < 100 %}
  Esto aparecera si la variable es menor que  100.
{% endif %}
```

**mayor que(>)**

```
{% if variable > 0 %}
  Esto aparecera si variable es mayor que  0.
{% endif %}
```

**Menor o igual que (<=)**

```
{% if variable <= 100 %}
Esto aparecera si es menor o igual a 100 
{% endif %}
```

**Mayor o igual que (>=)** 
{% if somevar >= 1 %}
  Esto aparecera si es mayor o igual que  1.
{% endif %}

Para mayor detalle busca la documentacion [Oficial de Django](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/templates/builtins/)

Comment: Esta respuesta no parece responder a la pregunta, Si no sabes como responder, visita [esta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) página